# XMLHttpRequest error only in IE

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

We use an XMLHttpRequest mock up object  to test our ExtJs 4.1 app with Jasmine. Now, everythings works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but IE versions 7 till 9 are making trouble as always.

There is an error at `onreadystatechange` function,

if `readyState` is `1` then `SCRIPT575` (cannot continue due to error `c00c023f`)

if `readyState` is `2` then `SCRIPT10` (required data not yet available)

See this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbaN6/1/) (search for "error" to jump to line)

Additionally, there is a error `TypeError: Object expected`.

---

**What I have read**:

I read a couple of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287706/ie-9-javascript-error-c00c023f) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903693/ie9-javascript-error-script575-c00c023f-prototype-file), but none of the recommendations fixed it.

---

**Note**:

in Chrome & Firefox all requests only return `readyState` `4`, but in IE `readyState` the values are repeated from 1 till 4 (?).

```
Chrome & FF
readyState 4 => OK
readyState 4 => OK
readyState 4 => OK
readyState 4 => OK
readyState 4 => OK
...

IE:
readyState 1 => error
readyState 2 => error
readyState 3 => OK
readyState 4 => OK
readyState 1 => error
...
```

---

Can you guide me how to fix this? I have no clue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a property named `response` that should be `responseText`.

Also, I am checking `readyState` with `if( typeof oXhr.readyState !== 'undefined' ) {}`

Now my code works in IE8, IE9 (Standard).

However, IE8, IE9 (Quirks) and IE 7 (Quirks & Standard) fail with error:

`SCRIPT16389: Unknown error`

I will try to fix, but this question is done.

Answer (score 1):

Check the readyState value before reading responseXML/responseText properties. If readyState value is 4, you can safely access responseXML/responseText

(The original implementation and later specification of XMLHttpRequest required implementations to throw exception on access to data before object has completed I/O operation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I check with `if( oXhr.readyState > 3 )` these errors are gone.But still, why are there 1-4 readystates in IE. Now, another error comes up `object expected` in ExtJs. I will check that and get back.

Comment: There is chance you are running sync requests, these may not trigger all readyState changes in other than IE9- browsers.

Comment: Yes I use `Ext.syncRequire` but also tried `Ext.require`. No difference.